# Foreach loop - looping over three lines of code with the same variable

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

This code gives me the message "The name 'item' does not exist in the current context". Obviously it's telling me that I cannot use the variable item three times, is there any way around this?

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.Items)

                totalSessionTime += TimeSpan.Parse(item.SubItems[1].Text);
                totalIdleTime += TimeSpan.Parse(item.SubItems[2].Text);
                totalActiveTime += TimeSpan.Parse(item.SubItems[3].Text);
```

Comment: Wrap everything below `foreach` in curly braces

Comment: try adding { } brackets, you can only add multiple lines when there are {} surrounding the statement

Comment: The indentation is for programmers, the compiler is not interested at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgot to add curly bracers around three lines:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.Items)
{
      totalSessionTime += TimeSpan.Parse(item.SubItems[1].Text);
      totalIdleTime += TimeSpan.Parse(item.SubItems[2].Text);
      totalActiveTime += TimeSpan.Parse(item.SubItems[2].Text);
}
```

without them only the first line (after `foreach`) would be called in a loop.

Comment: Yup this is correct, thanks for the quick response I am a novice. Cheers